# How to get more toggle hide/show div with different class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, toggle

I have a toggle that show or hide a div class. The status toggle is saved in local storage, so after page refresh the desired setting is maintained.

Now I'm trying to get another toggle that performs the same functions on a different class. I tried with a simple copy / paste changing the names of the classes and functions, but it doesn't work.

Can anyone give me a suggestion?

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/snake93/s0rx4ube/9/

```js
function save() {   
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("ck1");
    localStorage.setItem("ck1", JSON.stringify(checkbox.checked));  
}

function isChecked(isOn) {
    if (isOn === true) {
        $(".hideme").show();
    } else {
        $(".hideme").hide();
    }
}

//for loading
var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ck1"));
    document.getElementById("ck1").checked = checked;

console.log(checked);

$(document).ready(function(){
    isChecked(checked)
    $(".switch input").on("change", function(e) {
    const isOn = e.currentTarget.checked;
    console.log(isOn)
    isChecked(isOn);
  });
});
```

```css
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
  }
  
  .switch input { 
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  
  .slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
  }
  
  .slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
  }
  
  input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #2196F3;
  }
  
  input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
  }
  
  input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
  }
  
  /* Rounded sliders */
  .slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
  }
  
  .slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

/*END OF TOGGLE SWITCH*/

.hideme {
  padding:20px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox" id="ck1" onchange="save()">
<span class="slider round hide-off"></span>
</label>
<br><br>

<div class="hideme">Please hide me, but bring me back later ;-)</div>
```

Comment: Your example works for me, but I only see one slider.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify. I left the code as it is so as not to mess it up or create confusion. I can't duplicate the toggle and make it hide a different div.

Comment: An example. Here I have duplicated the code in Jsfiddle, but it doesn't work https://jsfiddle.net/snake93/rk689wqb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can have more dynamism by making better use of css selectors and adding an attribute with the same input id to the divs you intend to show/hide.

HTML:

```
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="ck1">
  <span class="slider round hide-off"></span>
</label>
<br><br>

<label class="switch">
   <input type="checkbox" id="ck2">
   <span class="slider round hide-off"></span>
</label>
<br><br>

<div class="hideme" id="label-ck1">Please hide me...</div>
<div class="hideme" id="label-ck2">Please hide me...</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    getLocalStatus()
    $(".switch input").on("change", function(e) {
       const element = e.currentTarget;
       saveStatus(element)
       setLabelVisibility(element.getAttribute('id'),element.checked);
    })
})

function getLocalStatus() {
    const checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');
    checkboxes.each(function(index,checkbox){
        const checkboxId = checkbox.getAttribute('id')
        var currentStatus= localStorage.getItem(checkboxId)
        if (currentStatus == "true") {
            currentStatus = true;
        } else {
          currentStatus = false;
        }
        checkbox.checked = currentStatus;
        setLabelVisibility(checkboxId, currentStatus)
    })
}

function setLabelVisibility(id,status){
   const label = $("#label-" + id + "");
   if(status == false){
      label.hide();
      return;
   }
   label.show();
 }

 function saveStatus(e) {   
    localStorage.setItem(e.getAttribute('id'), e.checked)
 }
```

Comment: It seems the solution that best suits my problem. However when the page refresh the status is reset and not stored.

Comment: Oops, my fault. I'm correcting it here. Only a moment.

Comment: Can you try it now friend? The getItem method of localstorage returns the value as a string and we need to pass the value as a boolean for the input check. That's why I was having problems... but I made a small adjustment with if/else that should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it is very useful to me. Everything works fine in JsFiddle. But I have another problem, since I work with elementor, do you think it would be possible to show / hide the div with a css id instead of label-for? This is because in elementor I can work with css class and css id and not with label-for. Maybe the same result using css ID instead of label-for would be better for me. How could I do ?

Comment: In `setLabelVisibility` function i tried to replace `label-for = '+id+'` with `id = '+id+'`. Then in the HTML I changed the `label-for` with `id`. It seems to work, but I don't know if it's a correct practice, what do you think?

Comment: I just edited the answer with an example using the ID as a selector.

Comment: Remembering that you need to somehow link the input you clicked with the label you want to show/hide and that none of them can have the same ID.

Comment: I was just going to ask you this. JsFiddle warns me of the error that I have duplicated ids. In fact, it doesn't work on my website. But you have already answered my question. Everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your show/hide DIVs different IDs and pass those into the function. (this is just one of several ways)

The element you want to show/hide needs a unique ID so we can differentiate it from the others, so forget about using a class as a selector here.  The toggle function takes two parameters, the element that called it and the element ID that gets toggled.  In the HTML below, 'this' will refer to that specific checkbox when its clicked. '#div1' and '#div2' are the IDs of the elements to toggle.

I've added in your local storage bit.

```js
function toggle(p, c){
    if ($(p).prop("checked")){
    $(c).show();
  }else{
    $(c).hide();
  }

  localStorage.setItem($(p).attr("id"), JSON.stringify($(p).prop("checked")));

}
```

```css
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
  }
  
  .switch input { 
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  
  .slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
  }
  
  .slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
  }
  
  input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #2196F3;
  }
  
  input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
  }
  
  input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
  }
  
  /* Rounded sliders */
  .slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
  }
  
  .slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

/*END OF TOGGLE SWITCH*/



.hideme{
  padding:20px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox" id="ck1" onchange="toggle(this, '#div1')">
<span class="slider round hide-off"></span>
</label>

<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox" id="ck2" onchange="toggle(this, '#div2')">
<span class="slider round hide-off"></span>
</label>
<br><br>

<div id="div1" class="hideme">Please hide me, but bring me back later ;-)</div>
<div id="div2" class="hideme">Please hide me, but bring me back later ;-)</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand how to implement the Js with code I already have. I replace it with this ? `function isChecked(isOn) { if (isOn === true) { $(".hideme").show(); } else {$(".hideme").hide();} }`

Comment: In the proposed way, the toggle loses the save function with local storage.

Comment: You're using classes as a selector, stop doing that! The div you show/hide needs to have a unique identifier so it knows which one to toggle, so give them a unique ID and pass that ID into the function.  I'll update my answer with more explanation.

Comment: I updated the snippet for your save function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but after page refresh the toggle status is not stored. I understand that I don't have to use classes as selectors, but I'm not very good at this, I structured the code based on what I found on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is another possible solution and one that I would prefer:

Change the input as so:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ck1" class="btn" data-toggle-id="#div1">
```

Then the javascript (with jquery) would look like this instead:

```
$('.btn').on('change', function(){
    var $d = $($(this).attr('data-toggle-id'));
    if ($(this).prop("checked")){
        $d.show();
    }else{
    $d.hide();
  }
    
});
```